# Centre of mass and objects tipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, statics, stability

[image]

In this picture if the only parts of an object in contact with a surface are the lines AB and CD am I right in saying that the centre of mass has to be in the area enclosed by ABCD (as shown). I think this is correct as if the mass lies outside this region taking moments about e.g.an axis AC would lead to a resultant  moment. If this is true please can you also give me a more generalised rule. thanks

Comment: You are correct. There isn't a more generalised rule, taking moments as you suggest is the correct way to analyse the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Each line $AB$, $BD$, $CD$ and $AC$ would create a hinge if the line of action of gravity does not pass through the shaded area.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a theorem about this, the mean value theorem in vector analysis. The centre of mass of an object is given by the sum of the mean value of each moment of the mass distribution,  $$\vec{x}_{\text{CM}} =\frac{\int_D \rho(\vec{x}) \vec{x} d^3 x}{\int_D \rho(\vec{x}) d^3 x},$$ and the mean value theorem states that $\vec{x}_\text{CM} \in D$ under certain conditions ($D$ connected etc).